# FME tester/testfilter equivalent for ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, fme-form

I've made an FME workbench with a series of  test filters that I want to replicate in ModelBuilder for Arc 10.2.

Anyone know whether this can be done easily?

Answer (score 1):

This can most certainly be done in ModelBuilder.  The TestFilter is essentially doing the same thing that SelectByAttributes would do in ArcGIS.  What you need to determine is what attributes you want to select by and the values they should have.

For example, when you say "series of test filters" I'm imagining you're filtering on a particular value of an attribute, then those features get passed to another filter and so on.  Eventually getting the features you want to do something with.

In ModelBuilder, the process would be similar.  You could use the **[Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000)** tool.

If this doesn't help, perhaps posting a screenshot of your FME workbench so we can try to help you better.

N.B., you can usually eliminate the need for multiple testfilters in FME by using a composite expressions.